# Migrating .sqlproj to Sdk style breaks certain database options

Tags: sql, .net, .net-core, dacpac, sqlpackage

I'm trying to migrate my existing `.sqlproj` targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2 to the new Sdk style project so that I can generate the `.dacpac` using the new .NET SDK. My new `.csproj` looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="MSBuild.Sdk.SqlProj/1.17.3">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <SqlServerVersion>SqlAzure</SqlServerVersion>
    <BundledNETCoreAppTargetFrameworkVersion>5.0</BundledNETCoreAppTargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>

    <CompatibilityMode>130</CompatibilityMode>
    <AnsiNullDefault>False</AnsiNullDefault>
    <AnsiPadding>False</AnsiPadding>
    <AnsiWarnings>False</AnsiWarnings>
    <ArithAbort>False</ArithAbort>
    <ConcatNullYieldsNull>False</ConcatNullYieldsNull>
    <NumericRoundAbort>False</NumericRoundAbort>
    <RecursiveTriggersEnabled>False</RecursiveTriggersEnabled>
.......................
  </PropertyGroup>
```

The second `PropertyGroup` is a 99% copy of the same element from the old `.sqlproj` - I want to be sure the new `.dacpac` is identical to the old one. The problem is a few of the configuration params are not respected by the new `.csproj`. If I generate a script from the new `.dacpac` with SqlPackage utility against the same database it contains the following which is not present in the old script:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM   [sys].[databases]
           WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')
    BEGIN
        ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
            SET ANSI_PADDING ON,
                ANSI_WARNINGS ON,
                ARITHABORT ON,
                QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON,
                ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT ON 
            WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    END
```

In other words, the params like `AnsiPadding` and `AnsiWarnings` and a few others are ignored. Moreover, I had to comment a few other params that caused the build to fail like `DbScopedConfigLegacyCardinalityEstimation`:

> System.ArgumentException: Unable to parse value for property with name
> DbScopedConfigLegacyCardinalityEstimation: Off (Parameter 'value')

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? I need to be sure switching to Sdk style project doesn't break my database which would be a disaster in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently they renamed a lot of things. So if you want to migrate your `.sqlproj` to the new Sdk style `.csproj` you need to be careful. `AnsiPadding` is now `AnsiPaddingOn`, `AnsiWarnings` is `AnsiWarningsOn`, etc.

```xml
<AnsiPaddingOn>False</AnsiPaddingOn>
<AnsiWarningsOn>False</AnsiWarningsOn>
<ArithAbortOn>False</ArithAbortOn>
```

Some non-boolean params are also changed. For example:

```xml
<TargetRecoveryTimeUnit>SECONDS</TargetRecoveryTimeUnit>`
```

Now needs to be (notice the casing, see [Time Unit enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.model.timeunit?view=sql-dacfx-150))

```xml
<TargetRecoveryTimeUnit>Seconds</TargetRecoveryTimeUnit>
```

Check the official [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Model documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.model?view=sql-dacfx-150) and always verify the generated script. I've successfully migrated my project and now use  `.dacpac` built from the new `.csproj` to apply my migrations.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer fixes the OP's problem because it forces the settings in the project to match the database. Another way of preventing the `ALTER DATABASE` statement from being generated is include a property that instructs all database options to be ignored.

```xml
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ScriptDatabaseOptions>False</ScriptDatabaseOptions>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

BTW, this question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620169/how-do-i-eliminate-the-alter-database-statement-from-my-ssdt-publish-script).